# Read tags other than <input> in a form by JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have the following HTML:

```
<form name="quiz" onsubmit="return Result()">
    <h3>1. What are the right order of the seasons?</h3>
    <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="a">a.  Spring, Summer, Autumn, Winter<br />
    <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="b">b. Spring, Winter, Summer, Autumn<br />
    <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="c">c.  Spring, Summer, Winter, Autumn<br />
    <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="d">d.  Summer, Autumn, Spring, Winter<br />

    <h3>2. Normally, how many days are there in a year?</h3>
    <input type="radio" name="radio2" value="a">a.  364<br />
    <input type="radio" name="radio2" value="b">b.  365<br />
    <input type="radio" name="radio2" value="c">c.  366<br />
    <input type="radio" name="radio2" value="d">d.  367<br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Answers">
</form>
```

I'd like to count how many  tags there are in the form but when I use document.quiz.length method, it only counts the `<input>` tags (it counts 9 elements for the snippet above) so I have no way to get to the `<h3>`. Can you please show me how to count the `<h3>`? Thanks!

Comment: Downvoting because it does not appear that you've put in enough [research effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/497418). As this question is easily answerable by using `document.querySelectorAll` it doesn't strike me as being particularly useful.

Comment: I am sorry I asked a basic question. I am very new to JS and ha've been encountering many issues but this forum has been providing a great help. I did research but could not find the answer, maybe I did not use the right keyword in this case. Anyway, thanks for your feedbacks. I've found my new interest in querySelector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is count how many tags are in the form ? Easy enough using `document.querySelectorAll` and the direct child CSS selector:

```
let tagAmoungInDatForm = document.querySelectorAll('form[name="quiz"] > *').length;
```

(
If you specifically want to count the `h3` then :

```
let tagAmoungInDatForm = document.querySelectorAll('form[name="quiz"] > h3').length;
```

)

You can also use `children.length` :

```
let form = /*select form*/;
let tagAmountInDatForm = form.children.length;
```

or `childElementCount`:

```
let form = /*select form*/;
let tagAmountInDatForm = form.childElementCount;
```

Comment: querySelector is my whole new world!

Comment: I'm sure you meant `querySelectorAll` ;) !

Comment: Yes, it is querySelectorAll. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You may use the method `document.getElementById("yourForm").childElementCount`. This method will count all the child of a html node. Explication: this method count all tags in a form or a div... You can consult [w3schools'](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_childelementcount.asp) documentation.

This function do the job:

```
function count() {
var c = document.getElementById("yourForm").childElementCount;
console.log (c);
}
```